# Querying Azure Freezes Android App

Tags: java, android, azure, cloud, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to integrate azure's app service with my app. In particular, I'm trying to store data on the database hosted by Azure. I can insert data fine, but whenever I try to retrieve it, my app freezes.

**MainActivity**- starts the activity and initializes the azure connection and table.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    /**
     * TODO: view data, put data in ordered lists, rate data, scheduler
     * **/

    Toolbar toolbar;
    ViewPager pager;
    ViewPageAdapter adapter;
    SlidingTabLayout tabs;
    CharSequence Titles[]={"New","Trending","Famous"};
    int Numboftabs =3;
    MobileServiceClient client;
    MobileServiceTable<Post> postTable;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        // Creating The Toolbar and setting it as the Toolbar for the activity

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        //manually set action bar color since not happening before
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));

        // Creating The ViewPagerAdapter and Passing Fragment Manager, Titles fot the Tabs and Number Of Tabs.
        adapter =  new ViewPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),Titles,Numboftabs);

        // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Assiging the Sliding Tab Layout View
        tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); // To make the Tabs Fixed set this true, This makes the tabs Space Evenly in Available width

        // Setting Custom Color for the Scroll bar indicator of the Tab View
        tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
            @Override
            public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
                return getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent);
            }
        });

        // Setting the ViewPager For the SlidingTabsLayout
        tabs.setViewPager(pager);



        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
                postPrompt();
            }
        });

        //initialize azure
        try {
            client = new MobileServiceClient("https://firechat.azurewebsites.net", this);
            postTable = client.getTable(Post.class);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //testing
        //Post post = new Post("haha, so funny :p");
        //postTable.insert(post);

    }


    private String makePost(String input){
        Post post = new Post(input);
        postTable.insert(post);
        return post.text;
    }
}
        return post.text;
    }
}
```

**Tab1**- a fragment that populates a list with data retrieved from the server. I believe my error is here when I try to query azure for the data.

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {
    MainActivity mainActivity;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1,container,false);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        try {
            //get data from azure
            mainActivity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
            List<Post> postList= mainActivity.postTable.execute().get();
            //List<Post> postList = new ArrayList<Post>();

            //set lists
            ListView newListView = (ListView) mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.newListView);
            NewAdapter newAdapter = new NewAdapter(mainActivity, postList);
            newListView.setAdapter(newAdapter);
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I solved my question. I left the answer down below and will select it as correct in a few days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out I was having the error because you must retrieve data from Azure using an async task. I left an example of one down below.

```
private void retrievePosts(){
        AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>(){
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    postList= mainActivity.postTable.execute().get();
                    Log.e("TAG",postList.get(0).text);
                    newAdapter.updateList(postList);
                } catch (final Exception e) {
                }
                return null;
            }
        };

        runAsyncTask(task);
    }
```